How to execute code at the same time while debiting user's account tables in PHP
I'm new to php. i have users plans table(beta target, beta kopa, beta flex and users table) when a user withdraws, it sometimes debit the users plan table and wont debit the specific user main account, sometimes it will debit the users main account and wont debit the plan table account. please why is it not debiting both table and users table at same time. i will so much appreciate any help please. below is my web.php route code
if ($eventz == 'transfer.success') {

    //inserting to history 
    
    $walletDb =  app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('transferInitiateProcess')->newDocument();
     
    $newDocument = $walletDb->set([
        
        'status' => $status,
        'amountSent' => $cus_amountSent,
        'createdAt' => $Cus_date,
        'balance' => $cus_totalAmount,
        'planTitle' => $Cus_selectedClient,
        'accountNo' => $Cus_accountNO,
        'accountName' => $Cus_accountName,
        'bankName' => $Cus_bankName,
        'email' => $Cus_emailz,
        'uID' => $Cus_uiDz,
        'initialAmount' => $Cus_initialAmount,
        'amountToDebit' => $Cus_amountDebitedz,
        'packageName' => $Cus_packageNamez,
        'ref' => $Cus_ref,
        'paymentMethod' => 'Bank Transfer/Debit'
       
    ]);
    //inserting to history 
    
    $lockPayment22 =  app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('AllPaymentHistory')->newDocument();
            
    $lockPayment22 -> set([
        'active' => true, 
        'paymentID' => $lockPayment22->id(), 
        'status' => $status,
        'targetTitle' => $Cus_selectedClient,
        'targetAmount' => $cus_amountSent,
        'packageName' => $Cus_packageNamez,
        'amountDebited' => $cus_total,
        'email' => $Cus_emailz,
        'authenticate' => '-',
        'uID' => $Cus_uiDz,
        'withdrawalDate'=> '-',
        'datePaid' => $Cus_date,
        'totalTarget' => '-',
        'paymentMethod' => 'Bank Transfer/Debit',
        'frequence' =>  '-',
        'paymentType' => 'Transfer/Debit',
        'deductionDate' => $Cus_date,
        'amountToCharge' => $cus_amountSent,
        'ref' => $Cus_ref,
        'credit' => 'Debit',
        'modeofPayment' => 'Debit'
    ]);
              
          
    /*debit from Users specific table balance */
    $addAmountToUser1User =  app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('Users')->document($Cus_uiDz);
    if($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Flex') {
        $addAmountToUser1User -> update([
            [ 'path' => 'flexAmount', 'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(-$Cus_amountDebitedz)]
              
        ]);
    }
          
    if($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Flex Interest') {
        $addAmountToUser1User -> update([
            [ 'path' => 'flexInterest', 'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(-$Cus_amountDebitedz)]
              
        ]);
    }
    if ($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Kopa') {
        $addAmountToUser1User -> update([
            [ 'path' => 'kopaAmount', 'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(-$Cus_amountDebitedz)]
            
        ]);
    }
    if ($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Kopa Interest') {
        $addAmountToUser1User -> update([
            [ 'path' => 'kopaInterest', 'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(-$Cus_amountDebitedz)]
            
        ]);
    }
    if ($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Target') {
        $addAmountToUser1User -> update([
            [ 'path' => 'targetAmount', 'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(-$Cus_amountDebitedz)]
            
        ]);
    }
    if ($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Target Interest') {
        $addAmountToUser1User -> update([
            [ 'path' => 'targetInterest', 'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(-$Cus_amountDebitedz)]
            
        ]);
    }
    if ($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Lock - 30 Days') {
        $addAmountToUser1User -> update([
            [ 'path' => 'lock3dAmount', 'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(-$Cus_amountDebitedz)]
        ]);
    }
            
    if ($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Lock - 30 Days') {
        $addAmountToUser1User -> update([
            [ 'path' => 'lock3dAmount', 'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(-$Cus_amountDebitedz)]
        ]);
    }
            
    if
        ($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Lock Interest') {
        $addAmountToUser1User -> update([
            [ 'path' => 'lock1yInterest', 'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(-$Cus_amountDebitedz)]
        ]);
    }
    if ($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Lock - 90 Days') {
        $addAmountToUser1User -> update([
            [ 'path' => 'lock9dAmount', 'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(-$Cus_amountDebitedz)]
        ]);
    }
    if ($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Lock - 6 months') {
        $addAmountToUser1User -> update([
            [ 'path' => 'lock6mAmount', 'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(-$Cus_amountDebitedz)]
        ]);
    }
    if ($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Lock 1-2 years') {
        $addAmountToUser1User -> update([
            [ 'path' => 'lock1yAmount', 'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(-$Cus_amountDebitedz)]
        ]);
    }
          
          
    //debit from users plan table 
         
    if ($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Kopa'){
        $OnlykopaHistory1 = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('OnlyKopaHistory');
        $query = $OnlykopaHistory1
               ->where('uID', '==', $Cus_uiDz)
               ->where('packageName', '==', $Cus_packageNamez)
               ->where('targetTitle', '==', $Cus_selectedClient)
               ->where('email', '==', $Cus_emailz);
        $documents = $query->documents();
        foreach ($documents as $document) {
            $getID = $document->id();
            if ($document->exists()) {
                $OnlykopaHistory2Debit = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('OnlyKopaHistory')->document($getID);
                $OnlykopaHistory2Debit -> update([
                    [ 'path' => 'totalTarget', 'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(-$Cus_amountDebitedz)]
                ]);
            } else {
                printf('Document %s does not exist!' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
            }
        }
    }          

    if
        ($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Target'){
        $OnlytargetHistoryTrans = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('OnlyTargetHistory');
        $query = $OnlytargetHistoryTrans
               ->where('uID', '==', $Cus_uiDz)
               ->where('packageName', '==', $Cus_packageNamez)
               ->where('targetTitle', '==', $Cus_selectedClient)
               ->where('email', '==', $Cus_emailz);
        $documents = $query->documents();
        foreach ($documents as $document) {
            $getID = $document->id();
            if ($document->exists()) {
                $OnlytargetHistory2Trans = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('OnlyTargetHistory')->document($getID);
                $OnlytargetHistory2Trans -> update([
                    [ 'path' => 'totalTarget', 'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(-$Cus_amountDebitedz)]
                ]);               
            } else {
                printf('Document %s does not exist!' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
            }
        }
    }

    if (($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Lock - 30 Days') || ($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Lock - 60 Days') || ($Cus_packageNamez == 'Beta Lock - 90 Days') || ($Cus_packageNamez == '6 months') || ($Cus_packageNamez == 'Lock 1-2 years')) {
        $OnlylockHistoryTrans = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('OnlyLockHistory');
        $query = $OnlylockHistoryTrans
               ->where('uID', '==', $Cus_uiDz)
               ->where('packageName', '==', $Cus_packageNamez)
               ->where('LockTitle', '==', $Cus_selectedClient)
               ->where('email', '==', $Cus_emailz);
        $documents = $query->documents();
        foreach ($documents as $document) {
            $getID = $document->id();
            if ($document->exists()) {      
                $OnlyLockHistory2Trans = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('OnlyLockHistory')->document($getID);
                $OnlyLockHistory2Trans -> update([
                    [ 'path' => 'totalLock', 'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(-$Cus_amountDebitedz)]
                ]);
            } else {
                printf('Document %s does not exist!' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
            }
        }
    }  
}
else{
    die("Check Failed!");
}

}
http_response_code(200);
exit();
}


This doesn't necessarily solve your issue, but you'll want to wrap these queries into a single transaction, so that either all of them happen, or none of them happen. (Does Firebase even have transactions? )

Please how can I wrap the queries into a single transaction, please

First hit in googling "firebase transactions": https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

The code you posted has several 'unmatched } characters at the end.

Unrelated to the problem, but get in the habit of using elseif or switch/case for mutually exclusive tests of the same variable.

I removed some codes that was why the curly brace is missing at the end
